# How to include column from component in natural id?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a venue mapping class like:

```
<class name="Venue">
        <id name="venueId">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <natural-id>
            <property name="name"/>
            <property name="countryISO2"/>
        </natural-id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="locale"/>
        <component name="location">
            <property name="countryISO2"/>
            <property name="city"/>
        </component>
</class>
```

The issue is that `name="countryISO2"` property from `natural-id` tag is not recognized in this way. I also tried `name="location.countryISO2"` which does not work either.

Can someone suggest how to solve this?

**UPDATE**:

Exception is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [countryISO2] not foun
d on nl.texxi.oct.model.Venue
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
```

Venue class is:

```
public class Venue {

    private int                    venueId;
    private String                 name;
    private Locale                 locale;
    private Location               location;    
    // getters and setters
}
```

and of course there is `Location` class which contains some fields like `countryISO2`, `city`.

In database, `venue` table contains: `venueId, name, locale, countryIso2, city` so basically Location is composition for some fields only on domain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to hibernate [DTD](http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd), This should solve your problem

```
     <natural-id>
        <component name="location">
            <property name="countryISO2"/>
            <property name="city"/>
        </component>
    </natural-id>
```

and you should remove `<component>` that's at bottom of the mapping.